# Connection failed on fetching docker image from debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, dockerfile

Newbee to rails and docker, getting error

> package 'libsqlite3-dev' has no installation candidate

**Base Image used - ruby:2.5.8-slim**

Code failing at line,
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl-openssl-dev build-essential libfontconfig curl

[image]

Note: Able to access deb.debian.org from browser as well as ping to deb.debian.org so there is no access issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the base image ?

Comment: @Philippe Sorry I am asking this to you but How to find the one?

Comment: In the beginning your `Dockerfile`, you should see `FROM ...` `...` is the base image

Comment: thank you @Philippe. It's FROM ruby:2.5.8-slim

Comment: issue is docker run ruby:2.5.8-slim apt-get update is failing at my machine

Comment: The problem is with the network : `Connection failed ...`

Comment: But there is no network issue at my end. One of the dev commented it can be a  failure to run basic debian update commands

Comment: @Philippe thank u for your time. Issue was, apt-get was blocked by company, they bypass it temporarily, now I am able to fetch that image.